# Porque recebo a mensagem de property is undefined mesmo com arrow function?

Tags: funções, react, undefined

Estou iniciando com react e não consigo entender porque do código abaixo não funcionar.
Recebo a seguinte mensagem:
**"TypeError: can't access property "aoClicarNota", this is undefined"**

Já estou utilizando o aoClicarNota como arrow function mas mesmo assim não funciona.
O que estou fazendo de errado?

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Button, ButtonGroup, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';

class BlocoNotasPossiveis extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            notasPossiveis: [
                {
                    nota: '1',
                    descricaoCurta: 'Nota baixa',
                    descricaoLonga:
                        'Serviços sempre apresentam falhas, com grande impacto na produtividade, gerando retrabalho constantemente.'
                },
                {
                    nota: '2',
                    descricaoCurta: 'Nota ruim',
                    descricaoLonga:
                        'Serviços sempre apresentam falhas, com grande impacto na produtividade, gerando retrabalho constantemente.'
                }
            ]
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="sombra">
                <ButtonGroup aria-label="First group">
                    {this.state.notasPossiveis.map(this.renderizarBotao)}
                </ButtonGroup>
            </div>
        );
    }

    aoClicarNota = () => {
        console.log("valor.nota")
    }

    renderizarBotao(valor) {
        return (
            <Button variant="primary" size="lg" onClick={this.aoClicarNota}>
                <span className="linhaNumeral">{valor.nota}</span>
                <span className="linhaDescricaoCurta">{valor.descricaoCurta}</span>
            </Button>
        );
    }
}

export default BlocoNotasPossiveis;
```

Comment: Quando vc utiliza componente de classe no react, vc precisa fazer o bind da função dentro do construtor. No seu caso, tente colocar `this.aoClicarNota = this.aoClicarNota .bind(this);` e veja se funciona.

Comment: @Colasanto Infelizmente nao funcionou fazendo o bind no construtor. grato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está na sua função `renderizarBotao`. Dentro dela, você tenta acessar `this.aoClicarNota`, mas não há um `this` definido no contexto da função `renderizarBotao`.

Precisamos definir um `this` para a sua função `renderizarBotao` e podemos fazer isso de duas formas:

1. Fazer o bind manualmente a partir de:
   `this.renderizarBotao = this.renderizarBotao.bind(this);` no construtor da classe;
2. Usar a sintaxe de `arrow function` para esta função também `renderizarBotao = (valor) => {`

Aqui um exemplo implementando `arrow function`:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-gp6io